# -bash: /var/lib/rancid/.bash_profile: Permission denied bash command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, sudo, su

-bash: /var/lib/rancid/.bash_profile: Permission denied bash command not found

I am trying to switch between the users ( krypton & rancid) in ubuntu 16.04 with 
 su -  . A few days back it worked perfectly, but don't know what happened now. The above warning message is coming.

When I am working as krypton user ~$ is showing 
But when I am trying to switch to rancid using su - rancid, the above error is coming and entering into the user with /$ at the beginning. I am not able to run some commands and it's interrupting me.

Please give me a solution. I am wasting all my time with this.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the permission of your **/var/lib/rancid/.bash_profile** file, and all parent folder. You can **ls -ld** them each, and put output here.

Then, you may check what there is in your **~/.bashrc** file.